# I want to have Sum of individual columns of two different table and show it in a single query result where customer id matches?

Tags: mysql

```
Create or replace view cnPointsDetailsvw
as select  sum(cd.value), sum(cd1.points)
from customerdetails cd left join
customerdetails1 cd1 on cd.customerid = cd1.customerid;
```

The problem is that the above query is calculating `sum` multiple times for the `column cd1.points`

Comment: what is `cd` and `ct`?

Comment: Ohh sorry the code would be like this

Comment: Create or replace view cnPointsDetailsvw
as select  sum(cd.value), sum(cd1.points)
from customerdetails cd left join
customerdetails1 cd1 on cd.customerid = cd1.customerid;

Comment: Instead of left join use `inner join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table customerdetails1 has only 1 row, so why you use `SUM()` function?
Just use `MAX()`.
I am confused of your table, so let me give a sample structurs and data.

table1

```
id   points
-----------
1    10
2    20
3    40
```

table2

```
id   points
-----------
1    10
1     2
1     4
2    20
3    40
3     5
```

And your query should be looks like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_name AS 
SELECT t1.id,max(t1.points) as points1, sum(t2.points) as points2
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Your view should be looks like this :

```
id  points1   points2
---------------------
1      10      16
2      20      20
3      30      45
```

Comment: Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: @NikhilKrishnan I updated my answer. please take a look.

Comment: No its not right logic, the customerdetails have 3 rows with id 1 and and customerdetails1 table have only 1 row with id 1 but when i am executing the above query the table with 1 row is added 3 times

Comment: its working with union all but instead of showing two columns its returning two rows

Comment: @NikhilKrishnan If customerdetails1 have only 1 row, Then `cd1` must be parent table. The leftjoin was inverted. I updated my answer.

Comment: @NikhilKrishnan I am a bit confused of your tables. Take a look at my updated answer. I also provide sample data.

Comment: yep  the  structure of table is same  but there is some little bit changes firstly : the table 1 can have multiple points for same id and secondly then i have to calculate the sum of points column in the table 1 not max value and rest same

Comment: @NikhilKrishnan Use `SELECT t1.id,sum( distinct t1.points) as points1, sum(t2.points) as points2`

Comment: Yep its working but have to add distinct in both columns Thanks @RubahMalam

Answer (score 1):

Do the calculation in subqueries, then join their results:

```
SELECT
 CD.sum_value, CD1.sum_points
FROM
 (SELECT sum(value) as sum_value FROM customerdetails) CD
 INNER JOIN (SELECT sum(points) AS sum_points FROM customerdetails1) CD1
   ON 1 = 1
```

Please note, that `SUM()` returns `NULL` if there were no matching rows, so the subqueries will return with exactly one record -> any `ON condition` will be fine which results to true.

If you want to group by customers, then do the grouping in the subqueries:

```
SELECT
 CD.customerid, CD.sum_value, CD1.sum_points
FROM
 (
   SELECT customerid, sum(value) as sum_value
   FROM customerdetails
   GROUP BY customerid
 ) CD
 LEFT JOIN
 (
   SELECT customerid, sum(points) AS sum_points
   FROM customerdetails1
   GROUP BY customerid
 ) CD1
   ON CD.customerid = CD1.customerid
```

**UPDATE**

To create a view (and bypass the limitation of MySQL), you have to create 3 views: 2 for the 2 subresults, 1 to join their results:

```
CREATE VIEW customer_value AS 
SELECT SUM(value) as sum_value FROM customerdetails;

CREATE VIEW customer_points AS
SELECT SUM(points) as sum_points FROM customerdetails1;

CREATE VIEW cnPointsDetailsvw AS
SELECT cv.sum_value, cp.sum_points
FROM customer_value cv
INNER JOIN customer_points cp
  ON 1=1;
```

Comment: More over i can't use subquery in from clause in view

Comment: Bro, always forgot that limitation in MySQL, the solution is to make 2 views using the subqueries, then joint them in the third view. (Quick example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9c99)

Comment: Ohh and bro, can you please tell me a bit more about "not working"? Possibly you are happy when your customers/users send you mail containing only one sentence: "Not working". Based on the info you provided it should work. If you missed to share something, it is not my fault, sorry. Sample data and expected results in your question probably helps next time to figure out what you really want.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience... the error i got is 
 
Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: And more over i don't want to make query more complex by creating multiple views is there any other optimized option . my Base requirement is i have two table with two columns each the first table have two columns named Custid and transdetails, second table have custid and redeem details, now i want to have sum of transdetails and redeem details where custid match in a single query

Comment: This depends on your data.. If you want a view and you have to use subqueries, then you can't avoid helper views (except if you want to replace the rdbms to one which allows subqueries in views).

Comment: its working with union all but instead of showing two columns its returning two rows

Comment: Then use the `UNION ALL` solution.